# Apache spark-streaming application output not forwarded to the master

Tags: streaming, apache-spark, flume

I'm trying to run the FlumeEvent example which is the following

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.flume._
import org.apache.spark.util.IntParam
import org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.FlumeUtils

object FlumeEventCount {
def main(args: Array[String]) {


val batchInterval = Milliseconds(2000)

// Create the context and set the batch size
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FlumeEventCount")
.set("spark.cleaner.ttl","3")


val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, batchInterval)


// Create a flume stream
var  stream = FlumeUtils.createStream(ssc, "192.168.1.5",3564, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2)


// Print out the count of events received from this server in each batch
stream.count().map(cnt => "Received  flume events." + cnt ).print()
stream.count.print()
stream.print()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

My sbt file is the following

```
import AssemblyKeys._

assemblySettings

name := "flume-test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.0.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-flume" % "1.0.0" exclude("org.apache.spark","spark-core") exclude("org.apache.spark", "spark-streaming_2.10")

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```

I run the programm with the following command

```
/tmp/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/bin/spark-submit --class FlumeEventCount --master local --deploy-mode client /tmp/fooproj/target/scala-2.10/cert-log-manager-assembly-1.0.jar
```

On the other side, the flume application is sending everything correctly and I can see in the logs that it's received.

I haven't made any changes to spark's configuration nor setup any environment variables, I just downloaded and unpacked the program.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

//edit: When I execute spark's FlumeEventCount example, it works
//edit2: If I remove the awaiTermination and add an ssc.stop it prints everything one single time, I guess this happens because something is getting flushed

Comment: I've exactly the same problem with Kafka. All is running but no result at the end of batch Do you've found the problem ?

Comment: so far I've managed to make it work by doing the following
                stream.map(event=>"Event: header:"+ event.event.get(0).toString+" body:"+ event.event.get(1).asInstanceOf[ByteBuffer].asCharBuffer ).print 


and for more complex things I have a function which returns anything I want to print as an rdd which can be printed with stream''s print method

I will post an answer when I have something that works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

....I should have learned to rtfm more carefully by now,

quoting from this page: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

> // Spark Streaming needs at least two working thread
>   val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[2]", "NetworkWordCount", Seconds(1))

I've been launching spark with only one thread
also the following works fine

```
stream.map(event=>"Event: header:"+ event.event.get(0).toString+" body:"+ new String(event.event.getBody.array) ).print
```